# B2C - Unable to output custom attribute in SAML response

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml

I'm trying to connect to a SAML SP, who require us to send them 4 claims. 3 of them are standard claims (surname, email, and objectId) but with different names, which I've been able to do just by using the OutputClaim's *PartnerClaimType* attribute in the RelyingParty. The other claim is one I've had to create a custom attribute for in the B2C portal, which I've have named employeeId, and the SP needs it to be called employeenumber.

I've read that custom attributes need to be preceeded with *extension_*, so I have added the following to our custom polcies:

SignUpOrSignInSaml:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_employeeId" PartnerClaimType="employeenumber" />
```

TrustFrameworkBase:

```
  <ClaimType Id="extension_employeeId">
    <DisplayName>EmployeeID</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Used when authenticating using SAML</UserHelpText>
  </ClaimType>
```

I've added the below into the AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId technical profile.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_employeeId" />
```

I've been using Microsoft's SAML test app to see what's in the response. The first 3 claims are fine, but the custom attribute never. If I give it a default value then it is in the response, so I guess for whatever reason the actual value, which I've only setup on one user account so far, cannot be found. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you enable extension attribute support? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#modify-your-custom-policy

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I do have the section to enable custom attributes in the policy, although after checking it again it wasn't quite right. However, after correcting it it's still not working.

Comment: Last thing to check is: the extension attribute you are targeting, does it contain the same GUID as the AAD-Common ApplicationId GUID?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I don't understand. Are you asking if the custom attribute name in the custom policy contains the same GUID?

Comment: Not in the custom policy, but the raw attribute name on the user object as returned by graph api - does that raw attribute name contain the same GUID as the one you’ve put in AAD-Common. It needs to match.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Sorry, my mistake. The employeeId attribute we're trying to use is actually one that's already built into B2C. So I've created this as a new claim in our base policy and also added it as an output claim in the AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId technical profile, which uploads fine. I've added it to our signupsignin policy as an output claim, but when I upload it I receive this error - "Output Claim 'employeeId' is not supported in Azure Active Directory Provider technical profile 'AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId' of policy B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml". Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: You cannot use the built in employeeId attribute. Supported list is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT OK, so we've created a new attribute called EmployeeNumber using the Graph API, so the full name is extension_<b2c-extensions-app-guid>_EmployeeNumber. Using Graph Explorer this is visible amongst all the data and has the correct value we set for it. The custom policies have been updated to use extension_EmployeeNumber, but when using the Microsoft test SAML app the attribute still isn't in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working by creating a new Technical Profile to output the extension_EmployeeNumber. This Technical Profile is referenced by a ValidationTechnicalProfile inside the existing SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email Technical Profile, which also has an OutputClaim for the extension_EmployeeNumber.